# Objc_msgSend and app crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsarray

When I trying to launch my app on simulator (3.1.3 , Xcode 3.1.4), it shows me objc_msgSend and application does not launch. This happens only when I **alloc NSMUtable Array** 
This is my code part,
in viewDidLoad,

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad{

   locationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"new delhi", @"faridabad",@"meerut"];
   str1=[locationArray objectAtIndex:0];
   str2=[locationArray objectAtIndex:1];

      [super viewDidLoad];
 }
```

Then I want to use locationArray objects in following method;

```
 -(CLLocationCoordinate2D) addressLocation1{

double latitude = 0.0;
double longitude = 0.0;
NSString *str= [locationArray NSString *str= [locationArray objectAtIndex:0];

    //NSString *str= @"new delhi"

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", 
                       [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
NSArray *listItems = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];


if([listItems count] >= 4 && [[listItems objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"]) {
    latitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
    longitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
}
else {
    //Show error
}

CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = latitude;
location.longitude = longitude;


return location;

   }
```

problem occur only when **alloc the locationArray,** whats wrong with me, please help
thanks

Comment: your `NSString *str= [locationArray NSString *str= [locationArray objectAtIndex:0];` doesn't make any sense change it.

Comment: `objc_msgSend` is not an error message; it's the name of a function inside the Objective-C runtime. Your problem has nothing to do with `objc_msgSend`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`locationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"new delhi", @"faridabad",@"meerut"];`

Try

`locationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"new delhi", @"faridabad",@"meerut", nil];`

From [The NSArray docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSArray) you see that for `initWithObjects:` it requires termination with `nil`.  If you don't want to do that, and you know how many you have, you can use `initWithObjects:count:`